# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: c#, configuration

I have a form that has a few text boxes, you input some values into the text boxes and then when you press submit it saves the values to a file.  However when I press submit, I get the following exception.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section add. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\Setup\HomeInventory2.exe.Config line 3)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at HomeInventory2.Services.Factory.GetService(String servicename) in C:\Users\Protego\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Services\Factory.cs:line 37
   at HomeInventory2.Business.Manager.GetService(String name) in C:\Users\Protego\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Business\Manager.cs:line 14
   at HomeInventory2.Business.InventoryMngr.Create(CreateInventory inv) in C:\Users\Protego\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Business\InventoryMngr.cs:line 19
   at HomeInventory2.Form1.submitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Protego\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HomeInventory2\HomeInventory2\Form1.cs:line 52
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

If I am reading it correctly, the problem is in my App.config file.  But I don't see any problem in that file - which is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <add key="InventorySvc" value="HomeInventory2.Services.InventorySvc" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<add key` should be inside like `<appSettings>`. There is no *configuration → add*. It should be like *configuration → appSettings → add*.

Answer (score 8):

Your configuration file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="InventorySvc" value="HomeInventory2.Services.InventorySvc"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

[appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - one of predefined configuration sections in .NET