# VB.NET Throws Exception while Compiling System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, my.settings

When i try to compile my WinForms VB.net project using dotnet 4.7.2 in Visual Studio 2022 Newest Version. This error comes System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException in this file: Settings.designer.vb, it also says that the configuration system was not able to be initalized. I´ve just create a new setting. Theres also an error when i change the strtup form, then theres a namespace problem but i can fix that.

When i run the exe directly after it is compiled nothing happends no error or something

I´ve tried remaking app.config
I´ve tried restarting my project/computer
And Nothing helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990706/system-configuration-configurationerrorsexception)

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Just a guess: Namespace not renamed in the settings-related XML-elements in app.config?

Comment: I´ve did not edited the app.config.